# Error: Permission denied to access property 'target'

Tags: javascript, events, error-handling, dom-events

How do I determine if the subsequent code has permissions in order to avoid the following error message:

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'target'

This happened in Firefox within an event handler for `dragleave`:

```
window.ondragleave = function(event) {
  if (typeof event.target == 'object') {
    var droppable = element_parent(event.target, (event.target.hasAttribute && event.target.hasAttribute('data-drop')), (event.target.nodeName != 'html'));
  }
}
```

- This issue is fairly rare occurring once a month across multiple domains
- This issue occurs in Firefox on desktops
- I have *not* personally reproduced the issue though the reports in error logs are highly reliable
- No frameworks or libraries

There is a [Permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API) though it does not seem accessible as of Waterfox 56 / Firefox 74B at `event.permissions` or `event.target.permissions`. I have made numerous attempts to directly reproduce the issue by dragging selected and non-selected parts of the page and "leave" the cursor away from various elements, form fields and the page itself though I see this error reported once every few weeks.

Suggestions?

Comment: Check it out https://caniuse.com/#search=permissions, may help u

Comment: Looks like this is the same or similar issue: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/pull/857? Might be able to pull some ideas from there...

Comment: That has something to do with iframes and nothing with the permissions API. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Property_access_denied I think it could help to check `window.self !== window.top` or `window.frameElement != null` first.

Comment: @Coli There are zero `iframe` elements on my site unless in the payment system and this error occurred on the blog (no `iframe` elements at all).

Comment: @John Well then maybe your site is an iframe.

Comment: @John can you see which version(s) of Firefox are having the issue?

Comment: @KevinLanguasco Gecko 56 and 74.

Comment: @John is Sentry being used to track these errors, or how? If so, what's the library version? do you have a stack trace?

Comment: @KevinLanguasco I don't use third party software except the fundamentals; I don't know what sentry is. This is literally some oddball timing thing with Gecko. I believe I triggered the error once myself without being aware of it, perhaps accidentally starting to drag something where nothing was meant to be dragged is a good possibility.

Comment: @John How are you doing the error monitoring then?

Comment: @KevinLanguasco `window.onerror = function(msg,url,line,col) {window_onerror(msg,url,line,col);}`

Comment: This may be related for those trying to avoid insanity: https://www.jabcreations.com/blog/gecko-permission-denied-to-access-property-bug-confirmation-and-fix

Answer (score 0):

Feel like I'm missing some context, like the html. But I don't think you should use ondragleave from window. I'd follow the basic setup with a div [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dragleave_event#examples). Build off of that.